# Jenkins pipeline specify agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to define my agent in a pipeline, I was trying with this

```
> pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'deploy||master'
    }
```

but it does not seem to work, the pipeline is always being deployed to the master, feel free to check my github https://github.com/cabrizio/jenkins-pipeline-test.git, I made it for test very simple.
Jenkins version  2.222.3.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're telling Jenkins to run the build on either an agent with the `deploy` label or something with the `master` label.  It's decided--for some reason unrelated to your pipeline snippet--to always use the master agent.

Comment: so what's the purpose to define it if Jenkins decides what to do? I am pretty sure there is such a way to do it , just need to figure out

Comment: If both of those nodes are equally good, why do you care which one it uses?  A node might be configured to be used sparingly, and another might be configured to be preferred.  There are other configuration options in Jenkins to manage load and how work is distributed, but they're not part of the pipeline.  If you have questions about that, then this question should probably be migrated to super user.

Comment: You told Jenkins, "I want my pipeline to run on either `deploy` or `master` label". Jenkins runs your pipeline on a node with `master` label, which fits your definition. If it would run on a node without any of these labels, there would be an issue, but as it stands, there is no issue here. If what you want is to run it once on `deploy` and next time on `master` etc., then you need to code it in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that will work but you don't get a choice of which one will be chosen.
If you wanted a more random effect then you could rename the agent's label from `deploy` to `deploy1` and in the Jenkinsfile have something like:

```
agent {
   label 'deploy'+new Random().nextInt(2)+'||master'
}
```

where the agent will look for either deploy0 or deploy1 or master depending on what is available. However, there is still nothing to stop it choosing `master` all the time. Or try the other way: `label 'deploy||master'+new Random().nextInt(2)` so that master randomly isn't there.